# Does this prove an equivalence of categories?

Tags: category-theory

The definition I am working with (I know there is a stronger notion) states that a functor is an $\textbf{equivalence of categories}$ if it is fully faithful and essentially surjective. I was reading a proof in which the author shows that categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are equivalent in the above sense by finding  functors $F:\mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ and $F':\mathcal{D} \rightarrow \mathcal{C} $ which are both essentially surjective. Does this really prove that $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are equivalent? Being surjective in both directions dictates a bijection of morphism sets?

Comment: No, having essentially surjective-on-objects functors in both directions does not give an equivalence of categories. I'm sure you can come up with a small (counter)example on your own.

Comment: The proof should give isomorphisms $FF' \simeq id_{\mathcal D}$ and $F'F \simeq id_{\mathcal C}$.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look for such an example!

Comment: What about a trivial category and another one object category with a single arrow $\alpha$ (with say $\alpha\circ\alpha=\alpha$)?